# EXCEL - VLOOKUP Different Sheets

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have 2 lists in 2 sheets. 
Each entry in both lists has an ID. The IDs in both lists are the same, but in different order.
I need to extract information from Sheet2 and put it in Sheet1 for each entry, based on the list. I use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1'!B12;Sheet2'!A:A;2;FALSE)
```

, but I get `#REF!` error.

```
=VLOOKUP(           -->the formula is located in Sheet1     
Sheet1'!B12         --> the ID
Sheet2'!A:A;        --> the column where to look for the ID (Sheet2, Column A)
2;                  --> the column from where I need to take the value (Sheet2, Column B)
FALSE)              --> I want the exact match
```

The real formula with the exact Sheet Names is:

```
=VLOOKUP('Measure List'!B12;'Total Cost Reduction per Month'!A:A;2;FALSE)
```

I use a German PC, so the `;` works as the English version `,`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the column you're selecting in the range to select from, I.e:

```
=VLOOKUP(           -->the formula is located in Sheet1     
Sheet1'!B12         --> the ID
Sheet2'!A:B;        --> the **range** where to look for the ID (Sheet2, Columns A and B)
2;                  --> the column from where I need to take the value (The second column in the range, i.e. Sheet2, Column B)
FALSE)              --> I want the exact match
```